# How do you customize the Azure BGinfo Extension or have it use a custom configuration file?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've deployed the BGinfo extension to a Windows VM in Azure, but I don't want to use the default configuration. Some of the info it shows is not relevant, and I want to add some other lines to the display.

How do I get the extension to use a custom configuration file?

The ultimate goal will be to deploy this on all my VM's using the custom configuration, if that's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I have the same question

Answer (score 0):

By default the extension installs to this location:

```
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.BGInfo\2.1
```

This is where the bginfo.exe and config.bgi files are stored. You can run BGInfo from this location, and using the GUI open config.bgi and make your edits as necessary.

The VM Extension adds an entry to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run with the following command:

```
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.BGInfo\2.1\BGInfo.exe C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.BGInfo\2.1\config.bgi /NOLICPROMPT /timer:0
```

This could be modified to point to a different configuration file, however I'm not 100% sure whether the VM Extension will auto-update this value back to the default config.bgi.